# PHP 5.4 500 Internal Server Error with display_errors off

Tags: php

I need PHP errors not to be displayed but logged. I am using PHP 5.4 My current code to log errors in my php.ini is:

```
log_errors = 1
error_log = "/path-to-file/error_log.txt"
```

Which works however I am getting a 500 internal server error trying to turn error displaying off using `display_errors`. I have tried using the following, all returning 500 errors.

```
display_errors = 0
display_errors = "0"
display_errors = false
display_errors = "false"
display_errors = Off
display_errors = "Off"
```

According to the PHP documentation, as of PHP 5.4, it is a string. What am I suppose to set `display_errors` to to turn error displaying off?

Comment: What server?  What method of executing PHP? FastCGI?

Comment: I am using Apache on Linux with 1&1 hosting. I'm not sure what you mean by "What method of executing PHP?" @Brad

Comment: So on your production code it's possible to get fatal error? How's that possible?

Comment: If I remember correctly, this is a server configuration thing, and not a PHP configuration problem.  Your errors are not being displayed... that part is working fine.  You just need to get your web server to not return the 500 status code and page when an error occurs.

Comment: @zerkms No it is not possible to get a fatal error, however I want to turn off displaying errors just in case I do get an error.

Comment: @Brad How is it a server config thing if I am using the php.ini to turn error displaying off?

Comment: @EthanH, I don't think you understand.  You **are** turning error displaying off.  The 500 Internal Server Error page isn't coming from PHP, but from your web server.  With display errors off, PHP returns to the server than an error occurred, and the server then takes it from there and returns that internal server error page.  You can configure your server to not do this, and simply return whatever PHP returns.

Comment: @Brad I am confused now. With the `display_errors` commented out I get no errors

Comment: @EthanH, `display_errors` defaults to `on`.  If an error occurs, it will be included in the output.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16457/discussion-between-ethan-h-and-brad)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a 500 error code means there is an invalid server configuration. This is most likely coming from Apache and not from php.

To get a clear understanding on what is giving you the error, look at your apache logs.

If you wish to also hide the 500 error, 
you could open your httpd.conf file and add

```
ErrorDocument 500 " "
```

Then make sure to restart apache. Any time you make a config change to php.ini or httpd.conf you will need to restart apache for it to take into effect.